# How to handle the same jQuery event handler on multiple elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, jquery-events

Suppose you have the following code to update many elements:

```
<div class='item'>
  Name:<input type='text' name='name' data-id='123' value='Name 1'>
  <button class='update'>update</button>
</div>

<div class='item'>
  Name:<input type='text' name='name' data-id='456' value='Name 2'>
  <button class='update'>update</button>
</div>
```

And JavaScript to handle the update:

```
function updateName(name, id){
  ...
}
```

What is the jQuery handler that can find the value and id and call updateName?

```
$('button.update').click(function() {
  name = ?
  id = ?
  updateName(name, id)
}
```

EDIT:

The expected behavior is that when the user updates the input field, the updated value is sent to `updateName()`, not the original value.

Also, note that the data-id and value are on the input, not the button.

http://jsfiddle.net/e3g6nfc1/8/

Answer (score 4):

Inside event handlers `this` is the unwrapped DOM element

```
$('button.update').click(function() {
  var name = this.name
  var id = $(this).data('id');
  updateName(name, id)
}
```

note that you want `var` in this case or else `name` and `id` jump out of the scope of that function and possibly become global variables.

[I've argued before that `this` is awkward and bad to use](http://togakangaroo.github.io/2014/04/29/on-this-and-new.html). You can achieve the same effect without using it like so:

```
$('button.update').click(function(e) {
  var name = e.currentTarget.name
  var id = $(e.currentTarget).data('id');
  updateName(name, id)
}
```

You also don't have to use jquery for data. on [reasonably modern browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=dataset) `$(domElement).data('foo')` is equivalent to `domElement.dataset['foo']`

---

**Edit:** Not sure if I missed this in the question or if it got edited but it seems like you're asking not for attributes on the button but the element *before it*. In that case you want [`$.fn.prev`](http://api.jquery.com/prev/) which will look something like this

```
$('button.update').click(function(e) {
  var $prev = $(e.currentTarget).prev();
  updateName($prev.name, $prev.data('id'))
}
```

note that this assumes that the input element is directly before the button. If you want to find the closest preceding input element you would use [`$.fn.prevAll`](http://api.jquery.com/prevAll/)

```
  var $prev = $(e.currentTarget).prevAll('input').last();
```

Comment: I'm not getting your link `this is awkward and bad to use` to be here in your answer...

Comment: @C-linkNepal Huh? basically my point is that `this` is a bad part of javascript. It's a parameter just like any other (if you only use `.call()` to invoke functions it becomes very obvious). The only differences are 1) you don't get to name it and 2) if you use the shorthand `fn()` syntax of invocation javascript just takes a guess at what it should be. Its almost always better to use a regular parameter instead.

Comment: I'm still not getting to be this in this answer. ( I don't suppose it to be there in your answer, it's not about `this`)

Comment: It's just another answer to the question - one that doesn't depend on the awkward `this` keyword.

Comment: I could explain further if you want to ask a specific question but it would have to wait a while as I have to leave at the moment

Comment: How does it get the name and id from the input when the handler is attached to the button?

Comment: @BSeven My apologies, I completely missed that part of the question. I've updated it

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

```
$('button.update').click(function() {
  name = $(this).attr('name');//to get value of name attribute
  id = $(this).data('id'); // to get value of attribute data-id
  updateName(name, id)
}
```

You may also use prop() method to get `name or data-id`:

```
name = $(this).prop('name');
id = $(this).prop('data-id');
```

But best is to use data() method for `data-*` attribute.

Comment: I believe `prop` is the preferred api for the name attribute

Comment: How does it get the name and id from the input when the handler is attached to the button?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why the answers here are trying to find the `input` attributes on the `button` element...

```
<div id="container">
    <div class='item'>
      Name:<input type='text' name='name' data-id='123' value='Name 1'>
      <button class='update'>update</button>
    </div>

    <div class='item'>
      Name:<input type='text' name='name' data-id='456' value='Name 2'>
      <button class='update'>update</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Delegating the events to attach only to the container (selecting only those children with `.update` class), catching them as they "bubble up". `previousElementSibling` used to target the `input` but jQuery selectors could also be used to find it if the layout were more complex.

```
$('#container').on('click','.update',function(e) {
    updateName(
        e.currentTarget.previousElementSibling.name, 
        $(e.currentTarget.previousElementSibling).data('id')
    );
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MrYellow/e3g6nfc1/1/)

Comment: In the JS fiddle, after entering a new name, I still get the value set in the HTML. I was expecting to get the updated value.

Comment: @BSeven `updateName(name, id)` "name" is actually "value"? or id? [JSFiddle update](http://jsfiddle.net/MrYellow/e3g6nfc1/33/)

Comment: Are you using the HTML attribute `name='name'` for anything? If not the usual setup is to have the stuff from `data-id` in the `name` attribute. name=value.

Comment: name is the value. It doesn't make much sense here because I have removed the other variables and fields...